# How to summon multiple mobs at once in Minecraft bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How to summon multiple mobs at once in Minecraft bedrock?  I think that's what Minecraft EDU is. (Zombies specifically)

Comment: You think that Minecraft EDU is what, exactly? And what does "zombies specifically" mean?

Comment: It means I want to spawn zombies.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to spawn a bunch of mobs at the exact same time. However, if you want to spawn a bunch of mobs all at once you can place a tower of command blocks and use `/fill` to fill the tower with redstone blocks to trigger all of them at once.
You can build the tower in this fashion. It is one block per floor and extensible to the height limit.

```
_C_
CRC
_C_

Key:
_: Air/Doesn't Matter (as long as not redstone-triggering)
C: Command Block (with summon command of choice, you can use Ctrl+MidClick to pick block with data)
R: Redstone Block to be placed with /fill
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for but thanks.

Comment: What *are* you looking for then? Do you want to just summon an infinite wave of zombies?

Answer (score 0):

You could use command blocks linked to a redstone circuit that would summon multiple at the same time.